# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in com.ibm.icu.text.BreakDictionary.main in SWT Application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.ibm.icu.text.BreakDictionary.main(BreakDictionary.java:40)
```

When I run/debug my SWT program in Eclipse. What might be causing this? When I put a breakpoint on the 1st line of my `main()`, it doesn't even seem to run till that point.

**UPDATE**

Even in a new SWT project, with a Application Window created from the template, without any changes, the error still occurs ...

If you want to see the code, http://pastie.org/3547493 (its whats generated from Eclipse with Google Window Builder Pro plugin)

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: @Tudor, as in update, in a clean SWT project, with a new Application Window created, it still has the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the `main` method of `BreakDictionary`. In other words: you are running a completely different program and not the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

In order to be sure that you are not running a different method from the dictionary class, you should right click on your class and run it as a Java application.